# How can I write a function that will format a camel cased string to have spaces?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to write a function that will take a string 'camelCased' and then format it to add spaces to it: 'camel Cased'.

Comment: Where is your problem? What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex to split on capitals and then rejoin with space:

```
.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ')
```

```js
let myStrings = ['myString','myTestString'];


function myFormat(string){
return string.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ');
}

console.log(myFormat(myStrings[0]));
console.log(myFormat(myStrings[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace upper case letters with a leading space.

```js
var string = 'camelCased';

console.log(string.replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will Help

```
 function replaceCamelCase()
    {
        var op="";
        for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
          if(isUpper(input.charAt(i))
          {
            op+=" "+input.charAt(i);
          }
          op+=input.charAt(i);
        }
        alert(op);
    }
    function isUpper(){
        if (character == character.toUpperCase()) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```